# How to use recursive PCRE regex to match nested css?

Tags: php, regex, pcre, recursive-regex

I am trying to use recursive PCRE php regex to recover individual results from nested css codes (strings):

```
<?php

//no recursive
$string = '{ color: #888; }';
$regex  = "/\{(.+)\}/";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

//attempt to be recursive
$pattern = '/{(?:[^{}]+|(?R))*}/';
$string = "
body { color: #888; }

@media print { body { color: #333; } }

code { color: blue; }
";
$regex  = "/\{(.+|(?R))\}/";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

The expected result would be something like:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "color: #888;"
  [1]=>
  string(21) "body { color: #333; }"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "color: #333;"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "color: blue;"
}
```

But, with this current regex I was not able to do that :(

For teaching/study purpose, I do need to use **(?R)** to get those matches.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/58505083/2191572 to get an idea of how to do it programmatically without regex.

Comment: Sorry MonkeyZeus, but I do really need this using regex for teaching purposes

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with recursion but https://stackoverflow.com/q/26385984/2191572 seems highly related.

Comment: PCREs recursion submatches are not capturable through the PHP interface.

Comment: Try `preg_match_all('~^[^{}\n]*({((?:[^{}]++|(?1))*)})~m', $text, $matches); print_r($matches[2]);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew empty: https://3v4l.org/0V4CP unfortunately

Comment: Use `m` modifier - https://3v4l.org/hoVtm

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, good, but I was expect a result with 4 string what would include "color: #333;"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `color: #333;` should be pulled out of `body { color: #333; }`

Comment: Ok, `$regex = '~(?=({((?:[^{}]++|(?1))*)}))~m';`, https://3v4l.org/FNXsj

Comment: As you know that you have balanced curly braces after, perhaps you might process it afterwards https://3v4l.org/CBKFK